# The plug-in is null : problem in an eclipse plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

when I try to test my plug-in I'm getting this weird problem as shown below:

```
Activator.getDefault()   // returns null here
```

Any clue how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much sounds like your plugin is not activated when you call #getDefault. 
Did you check "Activate this Plug-in when one of its classes is loaded" (aka "Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy" in MANIFEST.MF) in the manifest editor ?

Comment: Good answer. Yeah I do have that checked - screenshot is attached.

Comment: I suppose the code that would initialize the plugin instance var in the Activator is in place (normally in the start method of the plugin). 

`   public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    super.start(context);
    plugin = this;
   }
`

Did you ever put a breakpoint in place to see if it ever gets hit? What happens if you start the plugin manually in the osgi console?